# Normal Distribution / Central Limit Theorem

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I have a problem with some questions that say "calculate an interval within which 90% of the __ will lie".

I understand the how to find 90% confidence INTERVAL, but somehow when I subbed 1.645 into the equation, it does not give the limit of $μ $. When I did it backwards, the values of z was $±$5.46, which was out of the charts I read off z-scores.

Can anyone explain why? Am I missing a theory? Thanks

Here's the question for reference, just the last bit, 95% I can do

[image]

Comment: What have you calculated ? What is your $\overline X$ ?

Comment: What equation did you substitute $1.645$ into? (And why should it "give the limit of $\mu$", whatever that means?) What do you mean by "I did it backwards"? It will be hard to guess what your source of confusion is unless you show more of your work. My best guess so far is you are using the wrong formula because you think that the question about the white bars is asking for a confidence interval. (It isn't.)

Comment: You have a known mean and a known standard deviation for a normally distributed population.  Your interval should just be within $\mu\pm1.645\cdot\sigma$, or $176.2\pm1.645\cdot6.46$

Comment: @Brent that's what I thought but the answer was wrong, somehow they're not asking for confidence interval

Comment: @DavidK I used the z-score formula
$z = (x̄-μ)/(σ/sqrt(n))$
Sorry for the confusion - So I used $±1.645$ for z, objective was to find $μ$ similar to what Brent did above but I got the answer way off. So I took the answer key's answers for $μ$ and worked out the z to be 5.xx which is off the readable charts. I know I did something wrong but just don't know what

Comment: @LucasCK Brent's formula and application of it are correct, so in order to understand why it is "wrong" and help you out, we need to know more details. Who said it was wrong, and how did they say it? (By the way, we _know_ they're not asking for a confidence interval; what Brent described is an interval including $90$% of a given _known_ probability distribution, which has little or nothing to do with confidence intervals.)

Comment: @DavidK I re-read sorry misread early on I thought he did the same did I do. Could you explain that formula a little bit more? What does it mean on your last sentence? Is there a name for it  can google? You can post as answer i will upvote you thanks so much

Comment: OK, I've taken a shot at it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of confusion seems to be over the application of
a "confidence interval," so I'll try to start from basic principles.

In the first part of the problem (which explicitly asked for a $95$%
confidence interval),
you know some facts about the population of pink bars:
you know their masses are normally distributed, and you even know the
standard deviation of that distribution,
but you *do not know* the mean of that distribution.
Hence the problem is to make an intelligent guess as to what that mean might be.
Since you are unlikely to guess the mean exactly
(especially as you have only twelve measurements to go on),
your guess is a range of values, and that's your confidence interval.

A key fact about a confidence interval is that there is actually only
one value (the unknown actual mean of the population) it is designed to contain.
The fact that other values might fall within that range is not really important.

For the second part, you have a *known* mean and standard deviation;
in fact, you know essentially everything there is to know about the
weights of the general population of white bars.
In particular, you know (in principle, at least)
the cumulative distribution function $F(x)$ of the weights of white bars.

One particularly nice way to "bracket" the weights of $90$% of the bars
is first to choose a weight $x_H$ such that $F(x_H) = 0.95$.
This means that $95$% of the bars weigh less than $x_H$.
That's more than we need, so we next choose 
a weight $x_L$ such that $F(x_L)=0.05$;
then $5$% of the original population of bars weigh less than $x_L$
if we discard those bars from the set that weigh less than $x_H$,
we're left with $90$% of the original population.
In other words, the interval we're looking for is $(x_L, x_H)$
such that $F(x_L)=0.05$ and $F(x_H)=0.95$.

To figure out what $x_L$ and $x_H$ might be, we observe that
if $X$ is a random variable distributed like the weights of white bars,
then $X = 6.46\,Y + 176.2,$ where $Y$ is a standard normal random variable.
We know (or can determine from a table)
that $95$% of the standard normal distribution is less than $1.645$
and $5$% is less than $-1.645$, so we can plug in $-1.645$ and $1.645$
for $Y$ in the previous equation and read off the values of $x_L$ and $x_H$.

By the way, this particular interval is symmetric around the mean,
which gives it some nice properties. It is also possible to describe intervals
that are not symmetric around the mean, but unless we have a particular reason
to do that, I would use the symmetric interval.